# Как вложить класс в другой класс

Tags: python, kivy, вложенные-классы

Не могу понять как вложить класс в другой класс.
Решил сделать приложение на Kivy. Все сделал красиво как нужно.
А потом решил кое что добавить. и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В приложении есть меню.

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        box.add_widget(Label(text=''))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='',
                          on_press=lambda x: set_screen('')))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

кнопочки сделаны, нажал перешел, посмотрел что нужно.
и под каждый пункт в меню есть свой экран.

```
class Calc(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kw)

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kw)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kw)
```

Вот так примерно это реализовано. там тоже виджеты есть и все такое.
и в конце вот так.

```
def set_screen(name_screen):
    sm.current = name_screen

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(Calc(name='calc'))
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='Screen1'))
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='Screen2'))




class SScreen(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    SSreen().run()
```

и вот вопрос как добавить что-то в Sсreen, Sсreen1, Sсreen2. если там уже есть свой класс и свои виджеты.
я могу добавить кнопку или другой виджет, без проблем.
но когда я хочу добавить что то большое со своими классами и виджетами. Питон или вообще не чего не делает. Или выдает то что я добавил последнее. а куда девается что было изначально я не понимаю.
как это сделать.

если не знаете ответ то хоть может есть моменты, есть ньюансы на которые нужно обратить внимание. Подскажите.

Обьясните в чем ошибка?
Пытаюсь добавить в class Calc(Screen):
обычный калькулятор и не получается. хотя вроде все как по учебнику сделал.
если отдельно добавлять виджеты то все добавляется. а если их пробовать забиндить
черный экран и пустота. Питон тоже  не ругается.
Главное меню работает, а при переходе на новый экран пустота. где все.
вот что я пытался с делать в class Calc(Screen):

```
class calc(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(calc, self).__init__(**kw)

        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        back_button = Button(text='< Назад в главное меню', on_press=lambda x:
                             set_screen('menu'), size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))
        box.add_widget(back_button)
        self.add_widget(box) 

    def build(self):
        self.formula = '0'      
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        lbl = Label(text='0')
        box.add_widget(lbl)
        bt = GridLayout(cols=5)
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='^',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='%',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='√',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='!',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='C',on_press = self.add_oper))
        
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='7',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='8',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='9',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='+',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='<',on_press = self.add_oper))

        bt.add_widget(Button(text='4',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='5',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='6',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='-',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='(',on_press = self.add_oper))

        bt.add_widget(Button(text='1',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='2',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='3',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='*',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text=')',on_press = self.add_oper))

        bt.add_widget(Button(text='0',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='.',on_press = self.add_num))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='=',on_press = self.calc))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='/',on_press = self.add_oper))
        bt.add_widget(Button(text='+/-',on_press = self.add_oper))
        
        box.add_widget(bt) 

    def update_label(self):
        self.lbl.text = self.formula
        
    def add_num(self, instance):
        if(self.formula == '0'):
            self.formula = ''

            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()
            
    def add_oper(self, instance):
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()

    def calc(self, instance):
        self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
        self.formula = '0'
```

я понимаю что этот калькулятор не доведен до ума.
Но мне не понятно почему нет не чего на экране. чернота только.
Как правильно добовлять виджеты и как их биндить.

Answer (score 1):

Вы вкладываете класс `Calc` в несуществующий класс `Screen`. Нужно вложить класс `Calc` в класс `MenuScreen`.

```
class calc(MenuScreen):
def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(calc, self).__init__(**kw)

        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        back_button = Button(text='< Назад в главное меню', on_press=lambda x:
                             set_screen('menu'), size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40))
        box.add_widget(back_button)
        self.add_widget(box)
```